# Bluetooth stopped working after power outage

Tags: bluetooth, dell

My bluetooth always worked on this Dell XPS 13 but after a power outage it won't work anymore. I think wifi and bluetooth are in the same pcie module but I'm not sure.

On bluetooth settings it says no dongle.

```
lz@xps13:~$ lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a14 (rev 01)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a23 (rev 01)
0000:00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a27 (rev 01)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a13 (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1b (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1d (rev 01)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device a0fc (rev 20)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a0ed (rev 20)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a0ef (rev 20)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device a0f0 (rev 20)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e8 (rev 20)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e9 (rev 20)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a0e0 (rev 20)
0000:00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0c5 (rev 20)
0000:00:19.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0c6 (rev 20)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b8 (rev 20)
0000:00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b3 (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a082 (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device a0c8 (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a0a3 (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0a4 (rev 20)
0000:71:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Device 1101 (rev 01)
0000:72:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a09 (rev 01)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation Device 011a
```

There's nothing about bluetooth on dmesg.

lz@xps13:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue

nothing.

Ubuntu 20.04

```
uname -r
5.10.0-1023-oem
```

**UPDATE:**

after some reboots:

```
lz@xps13:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[sudo] password for lz: 
[   12.090787] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.090805] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.090808] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.090810] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.090812] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   12.165009] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   12.165011] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   12.165012] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[   12.165020] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[   12.165021] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[   12.165026] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   12.165052] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   12.165082] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   12.165087] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   12.165087] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[   12.165092] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[   13.778233] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.778235] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.778239] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

but I still see no bluetooth in the settings, it says it couldnt find a bluetooth device

Answer (score 0):

Could you try reinstalling the drivers? Maybe a failed update removed them during the session (but they were loading from RAM or cache).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple reboots, driver reinstall and different kernels did not work, but draining the battery and then charging again worked